# Show message at every page regardless page content

Tags: 7, rules

I need to show some message for user for every page at my site.

I've tried Rules action "Content is viewed" and I see message, but only when some node is displayed.
I **don't see** message when I open User page, or page with Taxonomy term, or some View page without nodes as content.

How can I show message at every page of my site regardless page content?
(Rules or Hooks or ...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to write it directly in the template? Or create a Block which you show in the header? or do you need to use the `drupal_set_message()` Message?

You can use "Drupal is initializing" event at Rules.

Comment: I plan to use drupal_set_message() as standard. I'll try use hook_init() as @wolverine said

Comment: OK, there is also a rule for "Drupal is initializing". Maybe you can use this so you can configure it instead of coding it.

Comment: "Drupal is initializing" works well. I can't find when this event triggers. But I suspect it's equal hook_init(). ty

Answer (score 0):

Implement `hook_init()` and set the message using `drupal_set_message()`. But as @lance asked, why can't you put it in to template?

Note : make sure you set `$repeat = FALSE` while using `drupal_set_message()`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by simply write

```
drupal_set_message('Message That You want To display');
```

this into your activated theme **page.tpl.php** .That message will be shown for every page.